# Check if string contains only letters in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

So I tried this:

```
if (/^[a-zA-Z]/.test(word)) {
   // code
}
```

It doesn't accept this : `"   "`

But it does accept this: `"word word"`, which does contain a space :/

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: How do you want empty strings to be handled?

Comment: are you wanting to check for letters only or word characters and spaces?  Even with the pattern fixed it will return false for "word word"

Answer (score 157, accepted):

With `/^[a-zA-Z]/` you only check the first character:

- `^`: Assert position at the beginning of the string
- `[a-zA-Z]`: Match a single character present in the list below:

  - `a-z`: A character in the range between "a" and "z"
  - `A-Z`: A character in the range between "A" and "Z"

If you want to check if all characters are letters, use this instead:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(str);
```

- `^`: Assert position at the beginning of the string
- `[a-zA-Z]`: Match a single character present in the list below:

  - `+`: Between one and unlimited times, as many as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  - `a-z`: A character in the range between "a" and "z"
  - `A-Z`: A character in the range between "A" and "Z"
- `$`: Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)

Or, using the case-insensitive flag `i`, you could simplify it to

```
/^[a-z]+$/i.test(str);
```

Or, since you only want to `test`, and not `match`, you could check for the opposite, and negate it:

```
!/[^a-z]/i.test(str);
```

Answer (score 22):

The fastest way is to check if there is a non letter:

```
if (!/[^a-zA-Z]/.test(word))
```

Comment: it should be `!/^[a-zA-Z]/`

Comment: @wrangler: no, if you write that, you will only check if the string doesn't start with a letter.

Answer (score 13):

You need

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+$/
```

Currently, you are matching a single character at the start of the input. If your goal is to match letter characters (one or more) from start to finish, then you need to repeat the a-z character match (using `+`) and specify that you want to match all the way to the end (via `$`)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
var Regex='/^[^a-zA-Z]*$/';

 if(Regex.test(word))
 {
 //...
 }
```

I think it will be working for you.

Comment: Hi, I think you should check again if this solution works. In my opinion there is no point using ^ twice and you should delete second one. You should also change "*" to "+" otherwise function will return true when word will be empty string or some amount of spaces. Correct me if I'm wrong :D.

Answer (score 0):

try to add **\S** at your pattern

> ^[A-Za-z]\S*$

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to check the string:

```
/**
 * Check null, should contain only letters, allowed space, min length is minLength. 
 * @param minLength 
 * @param string 
 * @returns 
 */
export const isStringInValid = (string: string, minLength: number) => {
    return !string || !string?.trim() || !/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/.test(string) || string.length < minLength
}
```