# Ensure user only enters string characters when prompted

Tags: javascript, html, string

When I ask the user how do I check they only enter a string and up to 10 characters?

```
function setUserName() {
    let myName = prompt('Please enter your name');
    if (!myName|| myName === null||myName !== string.myName) {
        setUserName();
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem('name', myName);}
    }
}
```

Stuck in a loop.

Comment: what do *you* define as "string character"s? a-z/A-Z only? How about 1, 2, !, &, ™ or š for example?

Comment: Try to replace all of your conditions with the Booleans that they evaluate to in order to debug this. for example: if(not True or True or False) to see what's going on.

Comment: Also, ```string.myName``` is an error. ```string is not defined```

Comment: Like @Bravo said, please clerify your question. It looks like you want the users Name, which could be quite a few different things. It could be a username. It could be a real name (allow spaces or not) etc etc. Be clear about what should be allowed and what not. Give some examples of what should be valid and some of what should not be valid.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression and testing the length of the string:

```
if(!myName || myName.length > 10 || /[^A-Za-z]/g.test(myName)) {
   //invalid input
}
```

It only allows letters uppercase and lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the stack overflow.

The strings can be treated as an array, you have the `length` method on them, so performing a `myName.length` would return you a length of that string.

And if you want to check the string for the characters (assuming only alphabets in the English language), then you can do it with the regexp: `/[^A-Za-z]/g.test(myName)`. For more details on regular expressions go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23476532/check-if-string-contains-only-letters-in-javascript).

Answer (score -2):

You can use `string.length` to find the length of the string:

```
let myName = prompt('Please enter your name');
if (myName.length == 0 && myName.length > 10){ //string has content and is bigger than 10 characters
    setUserName();
}else{ //a string less than 10 characters
    localStorage.setItem('name',myname);
}
```

Edit: forgot that prompt always returns a string

Comment: prompt always returns a "string"

Comment: That will return a string