# How to check if one string ONLY contains items of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Yo guys, I have an array of the alphabet and I wanna check whether a string only contains the items of this alphabet. If not, my bot kick a player from a game. I managed to write this script:

```
var letters =
    "a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z";
  var arrayLetters = letters.split(/ +/);
  var allLetters = arrayLetters.map((x) => x.toLowerCase());

  if (!allLetters.some((x) => player.name.includes(x)) {
    room.kickPlayer("Your name can't have strange fonts");
  }
```

Actually, this works but with names that doesn't contain a letter at all.

For example,  would be kicked but `nda` won't because there are some letters which are part of the array. How can I solve this? I wanna also keep players who only contains those letters in my array.

Thanks so much for the answers!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23476532/check-if-string-contains-only-letters-in-javascript

Comment: What you have checked is if the string contains at least one element of the array. For example `player.name = ["2","a"]` will always return` true` because there is at least to whom to check equality so your checking is not efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like there is a simple regex solution for this:

```js
var letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var regex = new RegExp("[^" + letters + "]", "i");
var players = ["", "nda", "Panda"];
players.forEach(p =>
{
  console.log(p, regex.test(p));
});
```

The basic idea is to match any characters that are NOT part of the `letters`

This particular case can also be shortned by using `[^a-z]` instead:

```js
var regex = new RegExp("[^a-z]", "i");
var players = ["", "nda", "Panda"];
players.forEach(p =>
{
  console.log(p, regex.test(p));
});
```

P.S.
You don't need separate your alphabet with a space in order to split it. `"abcd".split("")` would do same thing

Answer (score 0):

Regex is the best solution for you.

```js
var letters = "a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z";
var arrayLetters = letters.split(/ +/);
var allLetters = arrayLetters.map((x) => x.toLowerCase());
var regex = new RegExp(`[^${allLetters.join('')}]`, 'i');
if (regex.test(player.name)) {
  room.kickPlayer("Your name can't have strange fonts");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it the other way around. Use `some` to iterate over the name characters and test to see if they exist in `letters`.

```js
const letters = 'a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z';

function validLetters(letters, name) {
  const found = [...name].some(letter => letters.includes(letter));
  return found ? `${name}: ok` : `${name}: Your name can\'t have strange fonts`;
}

console.log(validLetters(letters, ''));
console.log(validLetters(letters, 'Bob'));
console.log(validLetters(letters, 'BOB'));
console.log(validLetters(letters, '123'));
console.log(validLetters(letters, 'nda'));
```