# how do i loop through all the letters in a string and see if all letters exist in a list

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a string and i need to loop through all of its letter including (if there's any) white spaces, numbers, symbols, etc...

I have to make sure that the string only contains letters, but my loop only goes through the first letter and then it produces an output straight away thus missing any symbols, white spaces in between letters.

i tried using for loop and even while loop but it's not giving me the correct output

```
for char in text:
    if char in letter_list:
        print('the word is in the list')
    elif char not in letter_list:
        print('the word is not in the list')
        break
```

example:

the string word is ca nada. there is a white space between ca and nada- if that's the case the output will print:
the letter is not in the list

Comment: Your `else` doesn't need a test. Either it's in the list, or it's not. There is no third case.

Comment: Can you give sample input and sample output? It's not clear what your problem is. What is `letter_list`? What are the rest?

Comment: As far as I can see, other than the 'elif' not needing a condition, the code should work on the assumptions that text is the text you're checking and 'letter_list' contains all the letters that you want to accept.

Comment: @tadman i edited the initial post to give an example!

Comment: @eybisea what does you letter_list look like?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Difficult to know what you want without knowing what is in the letter_list. Is the letter c not in that list? Please provide the contents of this "letter_list" for clarification.

This will loop through all the letters and print the correct line if they are in the list or not. I just removed the break

```
import string

text = "ca nada"
letter_list = string.ascii_letters


for char in text:
    if char in letter_list:
        print('the letter is in the list')
    elif char not in letter_list:
        print('the letter is not in the list')
```

Answer (score -1):

This...

```py
text = "ce nada"
letter_list = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

for char in text:
    if char in letter_list:
        print('the letter is in the list')
    else:
        print('the letter is not in the list')
        break
```

works if this is the expected output:

```
the letter is in the list
the letter is in the list
the letter is not in the list
```

Perhaps a more useful version might be?

```py
text = "ce nada"
letter_list = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

for char in text:
    if char not in letter_list:
        print(f"'{char}' is not a letter")
        break
else:
    print("All characters are letters")
```

Comment: i have to take ca nada as a whole word, so the output should either be 
" "
the word is in the list
" "
or
" "
the word is not on the list
" "

Comment: @eybisea Now you are referring to "words"? Before, it was "letters". Please edit your post and create a complete [mre], including sample input and desired output.

Answer (score -2):

Use regex, as per this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23476662/4400677

Alternatively: have a list of only valid characters - letters in an array, and check if every character matches.
I only recommend the more complex solution is your 'legal' characters are only in a non-ascii language.